# How can you spot the blow-up of $\mathbb P^3$ at a set of points not in general position?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

In [a previous question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/58926/blow-ups-at-points-in-non-general-position), it appears that a collection of points in $\mathbb P^2$ is in general position precisely when the blow-up of $\mathbb P^2$ at those points has no $(-2)$-curve. Is there a similar criterion which tells you when a collection of points in $\mathbb P^3$ is in general position in terms of the geometry of the blow-up of $\mathbb P^3$ at those points?

Comment: Could you try to make your question more specific? It is hard to know what you are interested in.

Comment: Let X be the blowup of $\mathbb P^3$ at m points. Whats the difference between the two situations namely; m points are in general position and not in general position. ( in $\mathbb P^2$ the situation is known).

Comment: Thats exactly what I have in my mind.

Comment: I don't have an answer, but I can at least provide a guess at the definition of "general position." Degree $d$ hypersurfaces in $\mathbb P^3$ form a projective space of dimension $\frac{(d+1)(d+2)(d+3)}{6}-1$. The degree $d$ hypersurfaces containing a given point form a hyperplane in that projective space. We say that $m$ points are in *general position* if the intersection of those $m$ hyperplanes has the right dimension, $\frac{(d+1)(d+2)(d+3)}{6}-1-m$, (or is empty if this number is negative) for every $d$.

Comment: It is not true that a collection of points in P^2 is in general position precisely when there is no (-2)-curve on the blowup.  For instance if 9 points are the base locus of a pencil of cubics, there need not be such a curve.

Comment: +Jack's comment: in the accepted answer to the question you (Sohail) quote Francesco mentions the exact same example that Jack does to support the claim that the description by the existence of $(-2)$ curves is only valid for a small number of points. Perhaps you should restrict the question to blow ups that still have a big anticanonical divisor. The analogous condition to the existence of $(-2)$ curves in higher dimensions would be that $-K_X$ is nef and big but not ample.

Comment: If I blowup 4 times and then consider; the four points lie on a plane and otherwise. Then whats the difference between the two situations.

Comment: A comment on terminology: as far as I know, being "in general position" should usually be a condition that holds on a Zariski-open subset of the configuration space. (More precisely, we say that a property P of tuples of points holds for tuples in general position if it holds for all tuples in some Zariski-open subset U_P of the configuration space.) Anton's definition seems to impose a countably infinite set of open conditions on tuples. In such a case one usually speaks of tuples "in very general position".

Comment: Dear Sohail, maybe the following is something like what you want. If one blows up 4 points in P^3 which lie on a plane to get a variety X, then the proper transform of the plane has numerical class D:= H-E_1-E_2-E_3-E_4 in N^1(X). (Here H is the pullback of the hyperplane class, and E_i are the classes of the exceptional divisors.) One can check that this class satisfies the intersection number formula D.(-K_X)^2 =0. If I understand correctly, no other effective class in N^1(X) has intersection number 0 with the 1-cycle (-K_X)^2. So coplanarity of the 4 points is equivalent to...

Comment: existence of an effective class D in N^1(X) with D.(-K_X)^2=0, or put another way, to the condition that the 1-cycle (-K_X)^2 is on the boundary of the cone of nef curves.